# How would I display a text box after an item in my menu is clicked. Android

Tags: java, android, menu

I am totally new to android development and I am currently working on my first app(will not appear on the market).I am using this app as a learning experience. I have no formal education because I am still in high school. My problem is that after a menu item is clicked, I cant get a text box to appear. Also, how would I add more items to my menu? 
Thank you(Sorry for my ignorance in android development... ).

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            actset();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
private void actset() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Developed By Shirwa Mohamed.. ");
}
```

Comment: Where do you want the text to appear?

Comment: in a popup box, after the about item in the menu is clicked..

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to get what you want is to show a [`Toast`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html).

Instead of using `System.out.println` in `actset`, try this:

```
Toast.makeText(
    getApplicationContext(),
    "Developed By Shirwa Mohamed.. ",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Thank You!! I think the problem was that I didnt get to look at Toast yet... Thank you again!!

Answer (score 1):

for the education purpose I'd propose to use `Toast` for a lightweight messages:

```
Toast.makeText( this, "Developed By Shirwa Mohamed.. ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

because `System.out.println` does not show up on Android screen.

If you want more golden stars, you may create full-blown `AlertDialog` box:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Developed by");
builder.setMessage("Shirwa Mohamed");
builder.setPositiveButton( "ok", null);
builder.create().show();
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, a `Toast` object may work for what you want. It will show a messages for a short amount of time and then disappear. However, if you want more control or would like to display more information then you may consider either an [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) which would show a small window displaying whatever information you wanted.

Or, if you want more functionality, you can create a separate class and declare

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

in the `<activity` tag of your `manifest`. This will show a separate `Activity` with a `Dialog` look. Then you just use an `Intent` to start that `Activity`

Comment: Thank You! I am learning more information in 2 minutes by reading these answers than I did in the past half hour on the development site.. Thank you!

Comment: @ShirwaMohamed  You certainly are welcome. This site is really good for that. Sometimes the Docs can be a bit confusing until you see the code in action or have a better idea of what that particular code can do. Good luck to you!